# Selenium.Support does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, .net-core

I am creating a new test project to test a .netCore web application (ASP.NET-RC1). I am getting "does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0" error. Is selenium not yet supported with .netCore or I am missing something? My dependencies:

`"dependencies": {
    "MyProject": "1.0.0-*",
    "NUnitLite": "3.0.1",
    "Selenium.Support": "2.50.1"
  },`

Comment: No, there's been no work on enabling the .NET bindings to work via .NET Core. Pull requests are welcome.

Comment: Still doesn't look like there has been any traction made on bringing support to .NET Core. See this issue: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1587